# Go Docker package not labeling image

Tags: docker, go

I have created a generic Dockerfile and established a Docker client in my go code.  I am able to build an image successfully in go using:

```
image, err := client.ImageBuild(
    ctx,
    buildContext,
    types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Dockerfile: Dockerfile,
        Remove:     true,
        Tags: []string{
            fmt.Sprintf("just/a:test"),
```

The image shows up in the `docker image ls` output.  But it does not have the expected repository and tag values, which I think are taken from `Tags` above:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
<none>       <none>    a34825be6ba1   16 minutes ago   72.8MB
```

What am I doing wrong?  I just want to name and tag the image.

Comment: This is exactly how [I used this](https://github.com/camerondurham/ch/blob/f4ababa289de10ad9691d670844dbb970a566c55/cmd/util/docker_service.go#L136-L141) and matches how Docker uses the client in their integ tests. Is there any `err` returned or other changes you're making to the `image`?

Comment: @tentative I am checking out your code, thanks.  Are you attempting to combine repository and tag into one string as in my example (your `imageTagName`)?

Comment: Yes, I tested providing your example ("just/a:test") and oddly, it parsed and added repository and tag in local image repo.

Comment: @tentative Strange indeed.  Thank you for taking the time to test, and for providing the code sample.  I'll rework it somewhat and see if I can chase the bug away.

Comment: Are you sure your Dockerfile is "valid" and builds successfully with the Docker CLI? Is `err == nil`? 

If the image build aborts for some reason, the `Remove: true` will not remove that failed build image when I tested it, so your intermediate image won't be tagged.

Comment: @tentative By reworking a little and looking at your code I was able to solve it.  I am curious why repository is included as a `Tag` since they are two separate things, but it seems to work.  Thanks yet again.